# Pulling One Row of Max Data from Multiple Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

I run a basketball stats site and I have a table called game_stats_lakers.

I want to be able to pull the max number from certain columns, points, assists, rebounds (totr), and then from whatever number that is I want to get the game id (gid) associated to that number.

I want to group it by all the seasons (sid) the player (playerid) was on the team.

Each game has only one gid, but obviously each stat max is probably from a different game. In simple terms, I want the highest point, assist, and rebound game for each player per season.

I want the query result to look like below.

```
playerid  sid    max_points  max_points_gid  max_assists  max_assists_gid  max_totr max_totr_gid
2         0304r  60          234             15           203              20       544
2         0405r  62          271             16           135              15       356
```

Does that make sense?

I just have no idea how to do it, I've tried so many different queries and they're all just never right.  Those are my actual field names (points, assists, totr, gid, playerid, sid), I just put random numbers as an example.

Thank you so much for any assistance!

The format of my game_stats_lakers table looks like this.

```
gid teamid sid   playerid min fgm fga 3ptm 3pta ftm fta points assists totr 
233 2      0304r 300      35  3   10  2    5    10  12  18     13      6
234 2      0304r 300      26  2   5   0    1    2   3   6      2       3
235 2      0304r 300      29  10  20  3    8    10  12  33     4       2
```

Using GMB's second solution below is close. I pasted my code and the result. The problem is the gid doesn't change for each season, the same gid is being carried down from the first season.  Here is the result.  Ideas?

Query run:

```
select
playerid,
sid,
max(points) max_points,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid 
    order by t1.points desc limit 1
) max_points_gid,
max(assists) max_assists,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid 
    order by t1.assists desc limit 1
) max_assists_gid,
max(totr) max_totr,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid 
    order by t1.totr desc limit 1
) max_totr_gid from game_stats_lakers t group by playerid, sid
```

Result here...notice the repeated GID's.

```
playerid sid    max_points  max_points_gid   max_assists  max_assists_gid max_totr  max_totr_gid
2        0304r  45          233              13           669             10        404 
2        0405r  42          233              14           669             8         404
2        0506r  81          233              11           669             12        404
2        0607r  60          233              16           669             11        404
```

Comment: `Does that make sense?` ... not to me, because I can't see the sample input table.

Comment: I've edited to show what my table looks like.  It's a pretty simple table.

Comment: you should post the data that will give the wanted result.

Comment: I did, I edited my original comment so you could see how the table is set up and where I need to grab the data from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do this with window functions:

```
select distinct
    player_id,
    sid,
    max(points) over(partition by player_id, sid) max_points
    first_value(game_id) over(partition by player_id, sid order by score desc) max_points_gid,
    max(assists) over(partition by player_id, sid) max_assists
    first_value(game_id) over(partition by player_id, sid order by assists desc) max_assists_gid,
    max(totr) over(partition by player_id, sid) max_totr
    first_value(game_id) over(partition by player_id, sid order by totr desc) max_totr_gid
from game_stats_lakers
```

---

In earlier versions, a couple of correlated subqueries may be a reasonable approach:

```
select
    player_id,
    sid,
    max(points) max_score,
    (
        select t1.game_id 
        from game_stats_lakers t1 
        where t1.player_id = t.player_id and t1.sid = t.sid
        order by t1.points desc limit 1
    ) max_points_gid,
    max(assists) max_assists,
    (
        select t1.game_id 
        from game_stats_lakers t1 
        where t1.player_id = t.player_id and t1.sid = t.sid 
        order by t1.assists desc limit 1
    ) max_assists_gid,
    max(totr) max_totr,
    (
        select t1.game_id 
        from game_stats_lakers t1 
        where t1.player_id = t.player_id and t1.sid = t.sid
        order by t1.totr desc limit 1
    ) max_totr_gid
from game_stats_lakers t
group by player_id, sid
```

Comment: I don't, so that won't work for me unfortunately.  I have an older MYSQL verison, 5.1.73.

Comment: @BrettNorton: I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: GMB, what's that score column?  I don't have a column for that.

Comment: GMB it's close, the problem is that the gid doesn't change.  The result just carries the game id over from the first row.  So the max numbers are right, but the gid is only right for the first season for each player.

Comment: GMB got it solved, see my final query in my answer above.  Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @BANONE: I see. It was unclear to me what `sid` was, now I understand it is the season id. I fixed the queries accordingly. I would suggest accepting my answer rather than posting another one.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I got it to finally work, I needed to add in the sid comparison and that brought out different gid's for each year.  Thank you GMB for getting me on the right path. Here is the final query that worked.

```
select
playerid,
sid,
max(points) max_points,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid
    order by t1.points desc limit 1
) max_points_gid,
max(assists) max_assists,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid
    order by t1.assists desc limit 1
) max_assists_gid,
max(totr) max_totr,
(
    select t1.gid 
    from game_stats_lakers t1 
    where t1.playerid = t.playerid and t1.sid = t.sid 
    order by t1.totr desc limit 1
) max_totr_gid from game_stats_lakers t group by playerid, sid
```